# Child element without root element in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, sax, stax

I have an xml document like this:

```
<root>
    <device>
        <v1>blah</v1>
    </device>
</root>
```

I want to parse this document, but just the

```
    <device>
        <v1>blah</v1>
    </device>
```

part. I want to ignore the root element. How can I unmarshal this with jaxb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your JAXB definition knows nothing about <root>, i.e. you can't just unmarshal the whole thing and look inside the resulting Root object:

1. Parse into a Document.
2. Use XPath / DOM traversal / whatever to get [a] reference[s] to the device Node[s].
3. Use unmarshaller.unmarshal (node).

Comment: If you leverage a StAX parser instead of DOM you will get much better performance:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22464911/383861

Comment: True enough, but "Advance...to the element you wish to unmarshal" may be non-trivial, particularly if you want to parse attributes of that element or you can't detect trivially by element name. Obviously if the document is big or there's a large amount of stuff after the element in question then you'd want to stream, but I'd (personally) stream only if parsing into a Document was prohibitive from a memory or performance perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Parse the XML with a StAX `XMLStreamReader`.
- Advance the `XMLStreamReader` to the element you wish to unmarshal.
- Use one of the unmarshal methods that take an `XMLStreamReader`.

**Example**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class UnmarshalDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Parse the XML with a StAX XMLStreamReader
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);

        // Advance the XMLStreamReader to the element you wish to unmarshal
        xsr.nextTag();
        while(!xsr.getLocalName().equals("device")) {
            xsr.nextTag();
        }

        // Use one of the unmarshal methods that take an XMLStreamReader
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Device.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Device device = (Device) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
        xsr.close();
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html